# using a DrawingBrush resource for a Grid Background

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am trying to set the background of a UniformGrid to a DrawingBrush resource and I am getting an error. How do I do this:

```
  <UniformGrid Rows="1" Columns="1" Height="75" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="2">
        <UniformGrid.Background>
            <DrawingBrush="{StaticResource SteelBrush_Vert}"/>
        </UniformGrid.Background>
```

Error: White Space is missing

This is the Steel_Brsh_Vert I am trying to use:

```
 <DrawingBrush x:Key="SteelBrush_Vert" Stretch="Fill">
    <DrawingBrush.Drawing >
        <DrawingGroup>
            <GeometryDrawing Geometry="M114.000,293.847C114.000,280.324,114.045,269.362,114.100,269.362L391.900,269.362C391.955,269.362,392.000,280.324,392.000,293.847L392.000,485.878C392.000,499.400,391.955,510.362,391.900,510.362L114.100,510.362C114.045,510.362,114.000,499.400,114.000,485.878z">
                <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="114,389.862" EndPoint="392,389.862" MappingMode="Absolute" SpreadMethod="Pad">
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDADADA" Offset="0.082" />
                        <GradientStop Color="#FF282828" Offset="0.854" />
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.949" />
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1" />
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
            </GeometryDrawing>
        </DrawingGroup>
    </DrawingBrush.Drawing>
    <DrawingBrush.RelativeTransform>
        <RotateTransform CenterX=".5" CenterY=".5" Angle="90"/>
    </DrawingBrush.RelativeTransform>
</DrawingBrush>
```

Comment: Can you post how you have defined SteelBrush_Vert StaticResource?

Comment: in my ResourceDctionary? or in my window?

Comment: It does not matter much in this case where you have defined it. I think the problem is in the SteelBrush_Vert resource. Just add the SteelBrush_Vert  definition to the question too.

Comment: Were you ever able to see anything I did wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Background property inline with the UniformGrid.
Try the code below:

```
<UniformGrid Background="{StaticResource SteelBrush_Vert}"
             Rows="1" 
             Columns="1" 
             Height="75" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Grid.Row="2"/>
```

Comment: now that was TOO easy. Sorry for being so stupid. THANK YOU!!!

Comment: Looking at the bigger picture, we sometimes miss the simple ones :)